# how recursion works inside a loop?

Tags: c++

I know that recursion means that a funtction calls itself. iteartion means there's a loop (while, do..)
the probelm I want to know how my program runs when it comes to have Recursion inside a loop: 
** this example will generate all the permutations of a given strin:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void string_permutation( std::string& orig, std::string& perm)
{

    if( orig.empty() )
    {
        std::cout << "perm: " << perm << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < orig.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::string orig2 = orig;
        orig2.erase(i, 1);
        std::string perm2 = perm;
        perm2 += orig.at(i);
        string_permutation(orig2, perm2);
    }
}

int main()
{

    system("color 1f");
    std::string orig = "123";
    std::string perm;  

    string_permutation(orig, perm);
    cout << "Complete!" << endl;

    cout << endl << endl << endl;

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I want to track my program. can anyone explains how it runs?

Comment: Recursion and iteration usually don't go together.  Can you explain why you have them together?

Comment: _"want to track my program. "_ You can do so with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive chain goes in depth to `size` calls plus one for empty string. Each recursion step calls `string_permutation()` `size` times providing string argument `orig` smaller by one symbol (`size - 1`). So, there are total as expected `size!` calls to `string_permutation()` to generate all possible permutations.

It can be describe as a diagram:

```
string_permutation: // top call for entire size N
    // start loop for smaller strings size = N - 1
    string_permutation:
        // start loop for smaller strings size = N - 2
        string_permutation: // loop step 0, size = N - 2
            // start loop for smaller strings size = N - 3
            string_permutation:
                //...
        string_permutation: // loop step 1, size = N - 2
        string_permutation: // loop step 2, size = N - 2
        //...
    string_permutation:
    //...
```

Tail call optimization cannot be applied for such kind of recursion.
So, you should expect that it creates on stack chain of `size` instances of local `std::string orig2` and `std::string perm2`.